# Event Registration Form Customization

Tags: civievent, registration

[image]

I am new to CiviCRM, I have this problem, for example in New Event Registration, it shows:
Tiny-tots (ages 5-8) - $ 800.00
Junior Stars (ages 9-12) - $ 1,000.00
Super Stars (ages 13-18) - $ 1,500.00

how can I remove the price amount label ,because I only want to show the amounts like:
$ 800.00
$ 1,000.00
$ 1,500.00
which template engine file should I edit?

I would appreciate it if anyone could help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be just to replace all the labels in the price field with an `&nbsp;`, then you will have just a bit of extra space there, followed by the dash and the amount.

Eliminating them completely so you can have the label on the backend but not show it on forms would not be easily done. You can see the code that generates these [labels here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/003d9ff3380764bf02623588d25d2fee4c9c91ef/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceField.php#L298), but you don't want to edit anything in core or else you'll have upgrade issues. I don't think you can alter any of this via [form hooks](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/list/#form-hooks), but maybe there is an argument to be made for adding a hook to make this possible.